# Batch File: command works in Main Routine - fails when called (using variable)

Tags: batch-file

I need help filling a knowledge gap.  Not sure why the handling is different, but sure there is a logical explanation.

The following code works from the main routine.

```
IF exist "%pathfile%.mkv" (
set file_error=0
) ELSE (
        set file_error=1    
        call :ERROR
)
```

However, after I got my script running, I looked it over remembering back to my structured programming college days and decided it should be cleaned up and organized more logically.  So I moved this file check to a sub-routine that could be called from the main.

```
:ISFILETHERE
echo "%pathfile%.mkv"   -->placed only for debug
IF exist "%pathfile%.mkv" (
    set file_error=0
) ELSE (    
set file_error=1
ECHO -----------------------------ERROR------------------------------------------
ECHO   %file%.mkv does not exist in %fullpath%
ECHO ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Explanation of the variables:

```
set basepath=\\opennas\media\Movies\
set basefolder=%~1
set file=%~2
set fullpath=%basepath%%basefolder%\
set pathfile=%basepath%%basefolder%\%file%
```

So %pathfile%.mkv is a variable storing the full path and filename (without extension) derived from the above combination of pre-set default + user entry.

If I do an echo on "%pathfile%.mkv" the output is what I would expect.  However it appears to have an issue with the `IF exist "%pathfile%.mkv" (`  It gets through it properly in the main but not when it's in the sub called from the main.  setlocal is set at the start of the file with no endlocal and no extra options.

output from attempt to run script:
`>mkv2wtv "Gattaca (1997)" "Gattac"`
The debug-echo inside sub which simply echos %pathfile%: `"\\opennas\media\Movies\Gattaca (1997)\Gattac.mkv"` (quotes are in the output as they should be)
The next line, which should be the If statement, errors: '\ was unexpected at this time.'

What am I missing, has to be something logical for why this works in the main, but the exact same code with variables having identical content doesn't work in the sub.

Thank You for having a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `IF` is parsed, the entire statement from the `IF` through to the closing parenthesis is is scanned and **ANY** %var% is replaced by its **PARSE-TIME** contents.

Consequently, the closing parenthesis in `(1997)` is seen as the closing parenthesis of the `IF` and ***THAT** converts the code to an erroneous format.

The cure is to escape that close-parenthesis with a caret (`^`) but this can be inconvenient if it's in a variable.

Here's some code that may assist:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET var=1234)567)89
ECHO %var%
SET var=%var:)=^^^^)%
ECHO %var%
```

Comment: Peter, Thanks for the reply.  The solution provided wasn't the root cause but the explanation got me going in the right direction.  The key piece of info I wasn't factoring in was that the IF statement was completely parsed including variables all at once.  My main block first checked for errors, then had a nested IF.  Something like this. 'IF any_error EQU 0 (call DETERMINEAUDIO IF %DTS% EQU 1 (CALL MKVDTSWTV) IF %DTS% EQU 0 (call MKVWTV) ELSE (echo Script exiting due to error))'  Based on what I know now, %DTS% was being evaluated prior to the sub that set it up.